# removing the accents from characters

Tags: c++, diacritics, wstring

I wrote this code to remove the accents from characters in a string and make the uppercase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
std::wstring input;
int main()
{
   input.reserve(255);
   cout << "Enter string to be converted:" <<endl;
   getline(std::wcin,input);
   for (unsigned int iii=0;iii<input.length();iii++)
    {
      if(input[iii]== L'ő') input[iii]=L'o';
      if(input[iii]== L'ö') input[iii]=L'o';
      if(input[iii]== L'ó') input[iii]=L'o';
      if(input[iii]== L'ü') input[iii]=L'u';
      if(input[iii]== L'ú') input[iii]=L'u';
      if(input[iii]== L'ű') input[iii]=L'u';
      if(input[iii]== L'é') input[iii]=L'e';
      if(input[iii]== L'á') input[iii]=L'a';
      if(input[iii]== L'í') input[iii]=L'i';
      input[iii]=towupper(input[iii]);
    }
 std::wcout<<input;
 return 0;
}
```

It makes normal characters uppercase, but ignores the accented ones and prints them in lowercase with the accents. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A more reliable method might be to use `iconv` to convert the text to ASCII and use the "transliterate" option.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely because `input` is a string of wide character, but character literals such as `'ö'` are not wide characters which means the comparison will fail. Use e.g. `L'ö'`.

Those comparisons should have generated warnings, and if not then you should turn on more warnings by the compiler so you get a warning for that.

Comment: @user1868866 And you change to wide character literals on _both_ the comparison and the assignment?

Comment: Yes. Also, I noticed that it was converting only a few character. It seems to works on `ű` and `ő`, but not the other ones. I edited the code in the question to what I have now.